# Multicolumn row line display

Tags: arrays, multicolumn

I am having a weird problem on a row line, with the following code :

```
\begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}
\small
\begin{tabular}{| l |*{3}{c |} l | l |}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{| c |}{\textbf{Title}}  & \multicolumn{3}{| c |}{\textbf{Model}} & \multicolumn{1}{| c |}{\textbf{Techniques}} &  \multicolumn{1}{| c |}{\textbf{Performances}} \\  \cline{2-4}
 & \textbf{Battery} & \textbf{EV} & \textbf{Grid} &  \\  \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
```

This give me the following header :

[image]

where the line for the last row "Performances" is not complete. Do you know why it happened ? If I remove this column, I don't have the problem anymore, I don't really get why it is happening.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another `&` in the second line.

I've also added `\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}` to increase a bit the row height.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
    \small
    \begin{tabular}{|l|*{3}{c|}l|l|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Title}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Model}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Techniques}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Performances}} \\ 
        \cline{2-4}
        & \textbf{Battery} & \textbf{EV} & \textbf{Grid} & & \\  
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Ecterion You're welcome, thank you for accepting my answer!